# Android Libgdx, How can i write to internal files?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

i have a serious problem, i need to export data to a file and the code it's okey, i haven't any error or exception, here the code.

```
public static void writeString(String path, String line, boolean append){
    FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local(path);
    file.writeString(line, append);
}
```

The file 'prueba.txt' it is empty.
I use the code here:

```
Utilities.writeString("prueba.txt", "Hello world!", false);
System.out.println("OUTPUT: "+Utilities.getLine("prueba.txt"));
```

And that is the output:

> I/System.out: OUTPUT:

On PC all works okey, only in android i have the 'error'

PD:Sorry for my english, it's very bad :/

Comment: Check the docs. You cannot write to internal memory on Android.

Comment: Use a full path. Not only a file name. On Android you can write to internal, external and removable memory.

Comment: @MrVansork Please show code of `Utilities.getLine()` method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't write on Internal File Storage of LibGdx, that is only readable.

```
FileHandle fileHandle= Gdx.files.internal(String path);
```

---

You can use Local File Storage of LibGdx for the same. This storage called [Internal storage](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) on Android. You can read and write to this storage but it is private storage of your application so only your App can access it.

```
FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local(String path);
```

Below codes are sufficient to write `HELLO WORLD` on `prueba.txt` that store in Local File Storage.

```
FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local("prueba.txt");
file.writeString("HELLO WORLD", false);            //write to file
System.out.println(charString=file.readString());   //read file
```

**EDIT**

If you want to write on external storage then use :

```
FileHandle file = Gdx.files.external(String path);
```

Make sure you have this two permission for `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

This permission is not sufficient if your Android target SDK is greater than or equal to API 23, you need to take runtime - permission from the user before proceeding any work related to your EXTERNAL_STORAGE. For current targetSdkVersion check your defaultConfig of android `build.gradle` file, if not present their check `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: I tried but i don't know why isn't working, im doing that correctly and in my AndroidManifest i have the permissons to READ and WRITE at external and internal storage, i don't understand anything with this problem because at PC all works correctly, but at Android not, im using Gdx.files.local(), my SDK API version is 25

Comment: I've tested on Android, working fine as expected, can you show me code of `Utilities.getLine()` method ?

Comment: public static String getLine(String path){
        String line = Gdx.files.internal(path).readString();

        return line;
    }

Comment: Why do I need permission for editing external storage in manifest if, as you said, Libgdx's local treated by Android as internal?

Comment: @MrVansork you wrote on local storage not internal[libgdx term] so why are you accessing through `Gdx.files.internal(path)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
file.close();
```

after the line:

```
file.writeString(....)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way, is use BufferedWriter, somthing like this:

```
BufferedWriter outColF = null;
    try {
        if(!Gdx.files.local(DIR).exists())
            Gdx.files.local(DIR).mkdirs();
        if(YOUR_FILE.exists())
            YOUR_FILE.delete();
        outColF = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(YOUR_FILE.write(true)));
        outColF.write(OBJECT);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
    } finally {
        try {
            if (outColF != null) outColF.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
```

This method works on Android and Desktop.